# How to import csv or txt file where there is no delimiter and commas represent missing values

Tags: python, csv, numpy, delimiter

I am trying to import values from a CSV into 10 columns: some have numbers and some have commas, but the commas are missing values so there is no separator:

```
2000-01-05,,-0.8803936956661669,,,,,,,-0.8316023477879247,

2000-01-06,,,,,,,,,,

2000-01-07,,,,,,,,,-0.3133976053851764,

2000-01-10,-0.26878027549229977,,,,,,,,,

2000-01-11,,,,,,,,1.0787295663966179,,
```

I tried the code below, but it removes the date column on the left side:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('Book7.txt', invalid_raise = True, usemask = False)
datanew = data[:,~np.all(np.isnan(data), axis = 0)]
```

Comment: The fact that `genfromtxt` works, indicates that the commas are indeed delimiters.  There's just missing data between successive commas.  `genfromtxt` is using `nan` as the fill value.  It also uses `nan` form the first column, which it can't convert to float.

Comment: What do you want to do with the first column?  It looks like dates, but won't fit in an array of floats.  Your last code line removes columns that are all `nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you want the missing data to be, but this code converts the date column to a datetime.date while setting missing values to NaN.

```py
import numpy as np
import datetime

def convert_iso_string_to_date(s):
    year, month, day = (int(x) for x in s.decode("ascii").split("-"))
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)

data = np.genfromtxt("test.txt", delimiter=",", converters={0: convert_iso_string_to_date}, invalid_raise=True, usemask=False)
print(data)
```

```
[(datetime.date(2000, 1, 5),         nan, -0.8803937, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,        nan, -0.83160235, nan)
 (datetime.date(2000, 1, 6),         nan,        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,        nan,         nan, nan)
 (datetime.date(2000, 1, 7),         nan,        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,        nan, -0.31339761, nan)
 (datetime.date(2000, 1, 10), -0.26878028,        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,        nan,         nan, nan)
 (datetime.date(2000, 1, 11),         nan,        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1.07872957,         nan, nan)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if numpy is preferred or mandatory. pandas can do this without extra codes:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = """2000-01-05,,-0.8803936956661669,,,,,,,-0.8316023477879247,

2000-01-06,,,,,,,,,,

2000-01-07,,,,,,,,,-0.3133976053851764,

2000-01-10,-0.26878027549229977,,,,,,,,,

2000-01-11,,,,,,,,1.0787295663966179,,"""

csv = io.StringIO(text)

df = pd.DataFrame([cell.split(',') for cell in csv])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           0                     1   ...                   9     10
0  2000-01-05                        ...  -0.8316023477879247    \n
1          \n                  None  ...                 None  None
2  2000-01-06                        ...                         \n
3          \n                  None  ...                 None  None
4  2000-01-07                        ...  -0.3133976053851764    \n
5          \n                  None  ...                 None  None
6  2000-01-10  -0.26878027549229977  ...                         \n
7          \n                  None  ...                 None  None
8  2000-01-11                        ...                           

[9 rows x 11 columns]
```

You may want to remove the empty lines though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply  use python builtin function:

```
from numpy import array

with open('Book7.txt') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

matrix = []
for line in data:
    if line != '\n':
        matrix.append(line.split(',')[0:10])
matrix = array(matrix)
```